# How to convert data from one format to other js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a project and I am getting the below data

```
{
  a1: { target: 'a2', overwrite: true },
  aa1: { target: 'aa2', overwrite: true },
  aaa1: { target: 'aaa2', overwrite: false }
}
```

I want to convert the above as below

```
[
  { source: 'a1', target: 'a2', overwrite: 'on' },
  { source: 'aa1', target: 'aa2', overwrite: 'on' },
  { source: 'aaa1', target: 'aaa2' }
]
```

How can I achieve this? Since I am new to js I am confused about this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please may you show us a [mcve] of what you've already tried? Consider using `Object.entries` and `.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = {
  a1: { target: 'a2', overwrite: true },
  aa1: { target: 'aa2', overwrite: true },
  aaa1: { target: 'aaa2', overwrite: false }
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([source, {target, overwrite}]) => ({
  source,
  target,
  ...(overwrite && { overwrite: 'on' })
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const obj = {
  a1: { target: 'a2', overwrite: true },
  aa1: { target: 'aa2', overwrite: true },
  aaa1: { target: 'aaa2', overwrite: false }
}

Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({
  source: key,
  target: obj[key].target,
  ...(obj[key].overwrite && { overwrite: 'on' }),
}))
```

Comment: almost ... but not quite ... there is no `overwrite: "off"` in the *required* output :p

Comment: @JaromandaX indeed! thanks, changed the answer

Comment: No probs, I like yours better than mine with Object.assign :p though I like Object.entries better :p